# R Shiny - How to determine that the App has stopped running?

Tags: r, shiny

My app requires connecting to a database, I am doing this using the RODBC package, I was wondering if there is a way to check whether the app has been closed either by clicking the 'x' box on the app itself or by clicking 'stop' in the R console. I'd want to then close the ODBC connection once this happens. Does anyone know how to check whether the app has been closed? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `session$onEnded()` to execute a function when the user closes the app like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$onEnded(function() {
    
    print('Connection Closed.')
    RODBC::odbcClose(channel)
    #RODBC::odbcCloseAll()
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Had no idea session was a thing, thank you!